# Is there any way to separate the class definition and declaration in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, action

I am new to AS3 and I want to organize my code as what I did in C++, which I can have a .h and .cpp file. Is there any way to organize code like this in AS3?

Well, what I want is at least I can define something like

```
public class Foo {

  // Function Declaration 
  public function myFun():void;


  // Function Definition 
  public function myFun():void {
    ..Do something...
  }

}
```

It will be even better if I can move the function definition part to another .as file.

Comment: ActionScript has the notion of interfaces, and are more-or-less Java-like interfaces.

Comment: "It will be even better if I can move the function definition part to another .as file". So you want a function in an .as file?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.  And while you could use a few tricks and extra lines of code to halfway semi-imitate this kind of syntax, I really wouldn't recommend it.  AS3's a little more restrictive about certain things like that than some of the more do-it-yourself, general-purpose languages like C++.

Answer (score -1):

As Wade said AS has interfaces, which can be used to define the public API of a class. Probably they're a little bit different from c++ header files, but it's been too long since I've worked with C++, so I'm not sure.

Interfaces in AS can only declare public methods. No restrictive access specifiers are allowed and no properties. There's a workaround for the property restriction though since in AS you can use getter/setters, which *are* allowed in interfaces.